# How to resign CKEditor Keybord in iOS7 on tap to navigation bar buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, ckeditor

hello friends I am using CkEditor in iOS7, Xcode 5  for editing in html and  then CKEditor keyboard appear like as and now i want to[image] resign keyboard form CKEditor on by tap  navigation right buttons .this is not related to neither UITextField nor UITextView because i had already tried to access UITexField and UITextView Delegates but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

on your navigation right buttons